# Send additional information when control flow item fails?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, ssis-2008

My *very simple* `SSIS` package has three `control flow items`: two of them do work, and the third sends an email when any of the two fail.

As it stands, if any of the items fail, I get a generic email saying that the package failed.

Is it possible to send the "Send error email" control flow item some additional information so that I know which failed? For example, if `Data Flow Task` fails, it can send some other information to `Send error email`. It can just be the name, but anything that helps me identify what broke.

This is what my SSIS package looks like:

[image]

This can easily be solved by adding a 4th item so that each item has its own *failure* process, but there has to be another way.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you want to create a separate "Send error email" task for each task that might fail?

Comment: This is one of my simpler packages. For bigger ones, I'd have to create an error task for every task the package includes.

Comment: But it seems that's the simpler alternative.

Comment: You'll probably be adding extra tasks anyway. You can either add extra mail tasks, or script tasks that set variable values (as in Tab Alleman's answer below).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a package-level variable to hold a context-sensitive message to be added to your email, and add a script task to the OnError event handlers of both of the other tasks that populates the variable with whatever you want the message to say for that task.

Then in your SendEmail task, you obviously read that variable to add it to your email text.

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable say DevErrorCode, set it 1 if task 1 fails, set it to 2 if task 2 fails and by default let be zero that nothing failed. on error flow you can set these variable using expression task. Before sending the email check the value for this variable and update your email body accordingly.